# Compromise between scipy.interpolate.Rbf and scipy.interpolate.griddata?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I need to generate a 2D density map given some unstructured `(x, y)` coordinates, and a `z` value which acts as the weight assigned to each point.

I can interpolate the values into a grid (see code below) using either [scipy.interpolate.Rbf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html) or [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html). The first one is very accurate but *very* slow, while the second one is *a lot* faster but noticeably less accurate.

See image below where `Rfb` is to the left and `griddata` to the right:

[image]

Is there some way to compromise between these two functions? Something that will produce a result more similar to the `Rfb` function but with a speed more similar to that of the `griddata` function?

```
# Data
N = 1000
x, y, z = np.random.uniform(0.0005, 0.03, N),\
    np.random.uniform(6., 10., N), np.random.uniform(1., 10., N)
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)

# Set up a regular grid of interpolation points
xi, yi = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 200), np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 200)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
# Normalize data and grid.
x_new, xi_new = (x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin), (xi - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)
y_new, yi_new = (y - ymin) / (ymax - ymin), (yi - ymin) / (ymax - ymin)

# Interpolate new data with Rbf.    
s = time.clock()
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x_new, y_new, z, function='linear')
zi = rbf(xi_new, yi_new)
print(time.clock() - s)
# Plot density map.
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi, cmap=plt.get_cmap('GnBu_r'), zorder=2)
plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, 2, colors='#551a8b', linewidths=0.5, zorder=3)

# Interpolate new data with griddata.    
s = time.clock()
# Python 2.7
vals = zip(*[x_new, y_new])
# Python 3.6
# vals = np.array([x_new, y_new]).T
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata(vals, z, (xi_new, yi_new), method='linear')
print(time.clock() - s)
# Plot density map.
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(
    zi, extent=(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), origin='lower',
    cmap=plt.get_cmap('GnBu_r'))
plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, 2, colors='#551a8b', linewidths=0.5, zorder=3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: `scipy.interpolate.griddata(
    zip(*[x_new, y_new]), z, (xi_new, yi_new), method='linear')` isn't working for me in python 3.6, replacing the zip w `np.column_stack((x_new, y_new))` gets me a plot instead of an error but the plot is wrong x size, `plt.imshow(
    zi, extent=(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax), origin='lower',
    cmap=plt.get_cmap('GnBu_r'))` seems wrong too, get matching cntour plot when commented out bu not colored same

Comment: @f5r5e5d for Python 3.6 use `np.array([x_new, y_new]).T` instead of `zip(*[x_new, y_new])`.